# Sometimes Fixed Navigation Menu

Tags: jquery, navigation, fixed

We currently have this side navigation menu on our website, which is working just great.

It has a somtimes fixed side navigation menu. What I mean by this is the navigation menu will scroll with the user but then remain fixed at the top of the page when it hits the top of the page just under the top navigation menu.

My Issue is, our menu is getting to be quite large and I would like to know how do I detect if the menu has hit the footer area of the site and for it to change to being fixed and stay above the footer links, as right now it ends up covering the content.

Is there any sort of easy way to do this ?

below is my code

```
<div id="productListNavigation-placeholder">
  <div id="productListNavigation">
    <ul class="categories" >
      <li  ><a title=" - NEW ARRIVALS"  id="new-arrivals" href="new-arrivals"  >NEW ARRIVALS</a> </li>
      <li class="current_item" ><a title=" - JEWELS"  id="jewels" href="jewels" class="current" >JEWELS<span class="category_arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="categories_level_1" >
          <li  ><a title=" -NECKLACES"  id="jewels-necklaces" href="jewels-necklaces"  >NECKLACES</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" - EARRINGS"  id="jewels-earrings" href="jewels-earrings"  >EARRINGS</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" - RINGS"  id="jewels-rings" href="jewels-rings"  >RINGS</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" - BANGLES"  id="jewels-bangles" href="jewels-bangles"  >BANGLES</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li  ><a title=" - FINE"  id="fine-jewelry" href="fine-jewelry"  >FINE JEWELRY</a>
        <ul class="categories_level_1" >
          <li  ><a title=" - PERSONAL"  id="-personal" href="-personal"  > PERSONAL</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" - FINE NECKLACES"  id="fine-necklaces" href="fine-necklaces"  >NECKLACES</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" - FINE BANGLES"  id="fine-bangles" href="fine-bangles"  >BANGLES</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li  ><a title="ZODIAC"  id="zodiac" href="zodiac"  >ZODIAC</a>
        <ul class="categories_level_1" >
          <li  ><a title="NECKLACES"  id="z-necklaces" href="z-necklaces"  >NECKLACES</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title="BANGLES"  id="z-bangles" href="z-bangles"  >BANGLES</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li  ><a title=" -  BOUTIQUE"  id="-boutique" href="-boutique"  > BOUTIQUE</a>
        <ul class="categories_level_1" >
          <li  ><a title=" -  NECKLACES"  id="b-necklaces" href="b-necklaces"  >NECKLACES</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" -  RINGS"  id="b-rings" href="b-rings"  >RINGS</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" -  EARRINGS"  id="b-earrings" href="b-earrings"  >EARRINGS</a> </li>
          <li  ><a title=" -  BRACELETS"  id="b-bracelets" href="b-bracelets"  >BRACELETS</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li  ><a title=" - STATIONERY"  id="-stationery" href="-stationery"  > STATIONERY</a> </li>
      <li  ><a title=" - AS WORN BY"  id="celebrity" href="celebrity"  >AS WORN BY</a> </li>
      <li  ><a title=" - GIFT VOUCHERS"  id="gift-vouchers" href="gift-vouchers"  >GIFT VOUCHERS</a> </li>
      <li  ><a title=" BLOG"  id=" blog" href="/blog/s-wanderlust"  > BLOG</a> </li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
jQuery(function($){
    var placeholder=$("#productListNavigation-placeholder");
    var message=$("#productListNavigation");
    var view=$(window);
    view.bind("scroll resize",function()
        {
        var placeholderTop=placeholder.offset().top;
        var viewTop=view.scrollTop();
        if((viewTop>placeholderTop)&&!message.is(".productListNavigation-fixed"))
            {
            placeholder.height(placeholder.height());
            message.addClass("productListNavigation-fixed")
        }
        else if((viewTop<=placeholderTop)&&message.is(".productListNavigation-fixed"))
            {
            placeholder.css("height","auto");
            message.removeClass("productListNavigation-fixed")
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/xQfW8/3/) solution.

In the code below i'm checking to see if the menu intersects with the footer. 
If it does it will move the menu up. When u scroll back up it will bring the menu back down to the original position.

```
$(function(){
    var menu = $("#productListNavigation-placeholder");
    var menuOriginalTop = $(menu).position().top;

    $(window).scroll(function()
     {
      var scrollyTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var footerTop = $("#footer").offset().top; 
      var menuTop = $(menu).position().top;
      var menuBottom = $(menu).offset().top + $(menu).height();
      var movement = (footerTop - scrollyTop) - ($(menu).position().top + $(menu).height());


         if(menuBottom >= footerTop)
         {
             // Moves menu up if it intersects the footer
            $(menu).css({top:$(menu).position().top + movement });
         }
         else if(menuTop < menuOriginalTop )
         {
             // Moves menu down if the menu is above the orginal position and menu is not intersecting the footer
             $(menu).css({top:$(menu).position().top+movement });
         }
         else if(menuTop > menuOriginalTop)
         {
             // if the menu get pulled to far down this will pull it back to the original position
              $(menu).css({top:menuOriginalTop });
         }

     });

});
```